# SSH frozen at "SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT"

Tags: git, github, ssh

I am trying to push my code to GitHub, but  `git push origin master` freezes. Running `ssh -vvv git@github.com` shows the last line (where I assume its hanging) is `SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT`. This only just started happening today, [GitHub status reports everything is operational.](https://status.github.com/) I haven't modified any configs before this started happening.

Partial verbose output:

```
...
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
```

Comment: What do your remotes look like? `git remote -v`

Comment: `origin  git@github.com:romanalexander/django-ratelimit.git (fetch)`
`origin  git@github.com:romanalexander/django-ratelimit.git (push)`

I haven't ever modified it manually, it was created with git clone. I've been using it without problem for the longest time.